# Как монетизировать desktop приложение?

Tags: windows, монетизация

Хочу разместить в своём приложении блок с рекламой. Приложение десктопное под Windows. Разрабатывала на C#/WPF. Можете посоветовать платформу, с которой можно заключить контракт и подгружать их рекламу? Желательно, чтобы выплаты были в криптовалютах и с таргентингом на англоязычные страны (ПО англоязычное).

Вижу, многие отговаривают от применения такого метода монетизации. Дело в том, что приложение простое. Приложения такого рода обычно бесплатные. Преимущество моего перед аналогами в приятном/гибком/современном UI при полной реализации необходимом пользователю функционала. Я не рассчитываю на большой поток денег. На разработку было затрачено не много ресурсов. Платную версию никто брать не будет. Реклама не навязчивая и размещена эргономично.

Comment: @donRumata Гуглила, но ничего не нашла. Например, appodeal.com делает выплаты криптовалютами, но он только под мобильные приложения. Много сервисов пересмотрела, но не нашла то, что ищу. Может неправильные ключевые слова использую при поиске сервисов?

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, к вам персонально это не относится, но вы не представляете, как у меня бомбит от этой темы! Когда я вижу рекламу в приложении, я его моментально удаляю, даже если оно мне реально нужно. Считаю что реклама и вирусы - это абсолютно идентичные вещи. Если ваше приложение является коммерческим и на первом месте у вас деньги, то о способах монетизации нужно думать в первую очередь, ДО того как вы начинаете его разрабатывать! И здесь вашей задачей стоит понять, какая вообще польза для людей от вашего приложения, после чего найти ряд услуг, которые вы сможете предоставить платно.

Comment: donRumata, видимо, имел в виду заключение контракта на рекламу с компанией Google, а не поиск ответа в одноименном поисковике (просто это выглядит логичным).

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf, бомбит - не пользуйтесь, это же не принудительно. Автор вложил кучу труда, и даже не просит с вас денег, а вы тут претензии выкатываете, что вас не в той форме обеспечили халявой. Попробуйте написать что-нибудь свое для начала, прежде чем поучать других как им надо зарабатывать.

Comment: @freim ну зачем Вы так агрессивно? Я тоже считаю, что реклама в Win-приложениях не совсем уместна. Хотя тут дело в подаче. Если не слишком навязчиво - то почему бы и нет? С другой стороны, я бы предпочел заплатить за некоторые доп.фичи (полезные!) лишь бы не видеть эту рекламу. С товарищем *Beast Winterwolf* согласен в том, что неплохо бы сначала понять - что дает приложение? Если оно полезное - такое лучше продавать (покупатели найдутся, особенно за рубежом), если это какой-нибудь "повременный сменщик обоев рабочего стола", то можно не заморачиваться: его сразу же "снесут".

Comment: @freim с чего вы взяли, что я не писал ничего своего? Я собственно по той причине и высказался, что сам сталкивался с точно такой же ситуацией.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf - так расскажите подробнее, что вы сделали и с каким результатом. Чтобы ТС это реально могло помочь, а не в формате что лучше быть богатым и здоровым. Лично я бы тоже с удовольствием почитал бы про интересный кейс. Тема-то очень непростая, и рабочий вариант найти очень нелегко.

Comment: Дело не в том,что *все мы поголовно* противники рекламы. Но необходимо понимать, что реклама должна быть оправдана. Одно дело - реклама в торрент-клиенте (поставил закачку, свернул в трей и все). Совсем другое - реклама в приложении для повседневного использования. Хотя опять же, все зависит от способа подачи. Мне, например, импонирует способ рекламы в старых версиях программы `DownloadManager` (новыми версиями не пользовался). В конце концов, расскажите, что у Вас за программа, что она выполняет? Просто интересно. Может, Вы неправильно ее оценили и за такое стоит платить *реальными* деньгами?

Comment: Да. @Dima прав, я имел ввиду, что гугл - один из самых крупных поставщиков рекламы. Он собсно существует на бабки от фирм, которые хотят, чтобы про них узнали.

Comment: @freim на эту тему можно очень много чего сказать. Если в двух словах, то я банально сделал свой продукт платным, потому что не продумал всё заранее, мне искренне хотелось бы сделать бесплатную версию и в будущем я буду серьёзнее обдумывать эти детали. С вашим ответом я абсолютно согласен в том плане, что реклама приносит копейки, а видеть её неприятно ни мне, ни клиентам.

Comment: @Beast Winterwolf, реклама не подарок, согласен, но не все так просто. Если лет 15-20 назад можно было продавать условный CD Ejector тысячами копий, то сейчас ситуация очень сильно изменилась, и люди покупают только то, без чего абсолютно невозможно обойтись. И если нет хорошей перспективы продавать на корпоративном рынке, то остается только вариант непрямых продаж, что обычно сводится к рекламе в той или иной форме. Другое дело, что для этого нужны просто чудовищные цифры инсталляций, но тут уже автору видней.

Answer (score 4):

Регулярно приходит такой спам, обычно предлагают рекламную обертку для инсталлятора. Из последних осталась только [эта ссылка](http://developers.oneaudience.com), даже не разбирался что это такое. Microsoft сейчас [предлагает](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/store/monetize/ads-in-apps) монетизацию UWP приложений. Проще всего наберите в гугле "*Monetize your app with ads*" и получите массу вариантов.

Насчет выплат в криптовалюте это серьезное требование, конечно. Даже если такая платформа и найдется, не факт, что вы сами захотите с ними работать, условия у них вряд ли будут хорошими..

Вообще надо прежде всего оценивать число установок. У вас будет число установок хотя бы от 100 тысяч в месяц? Вот смотрите какая арифметика: допустим, вашу программу устанавливают в месяц 10000 человек. С каждого клика по рекламному блоку вы получаете 10 центов. Кликает 1% пользователей. Итого месячный заработок составит 10000*0.1*0.01, то есть 10 долларов. Арифметика предельно упрощенная, но порядок цифр именно такой. Так что лучше прикиньте сразу что вы можете заработать, а то может не стоит и связываться.

Могу еще посоветовать не ограничиваться рекламой в приложении, а сделать под это приложение сайт с Адсенсом. Кроме самого приложения, там, разумеется, должно быть дополнительное наполнение на сопутствующую тему. Причем реклама на сайте скорее всего будет давать больше, чем встроенная в приложение реклама - например, даже если пользователь решил не скачивать, он может уйти с сайта кликом на баннер.

Comment: Я уже натыкалась на монетизацию UWP приложений от microsoft. Почему-то с MSDN перешла на adduplex.com, но что-то мне в нём не понравилось. Окей, покопаюсь в этом. Спасибо за помощь

Comment: Запросы на подобии "Monetize your app with ads" вводила до того, как попросила помощи здесь. Практически все результаты были по внедрению рекламы в мобильное приложение. То, что предлагает Microsoft, ориентировано на наличие приложения в Microsoft Store. В таком случае теряются пользователи Windows 7. Распространение ПО будет не через Microsoft Store. Поэтому это не актуальный вариант. Кстати, обновила вопрос.

Comment: @J. Huxley - да, агрегаторы рекламы сейчас почти полностью переориентировались на мобильные приложения - вслед за пользователями. Большинство домашних пользователей переехало с ПК на планшеты, и ПК сейчас возвращаются в их исходную нишу рабочих станций. Кстати, я немного дополнил ответ.

Comment: Решением оказалось написание текстового запроса на размещение рекламы в Windows desktop app разным платформам по размещению рекламы. С некоторыми сейчас ведётся обсуждение данного процесса. Большинство - сервисы, работающие с веб-страницами.

Answer (score 0):

Могу посоветовать следующий вариант.
1. На своем сайте вы размещаете рекламный блок яндекс, google или еще кого хотите.
2. В приложении используете элемент WebBrowser и открываете в нем свой сайт.
Все довольно просто.